# Error finding callig15

Tags: fonts, ubuntu

The font calligra is not working on my system (Ubuntu, installed LaTeX by installing Texmaker, which installs the dependencies).

When I try to compile this minimal example at the command line,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calligra}
\begin{document}
\calligra
This is a test of a calligraphy font.
\normalfont
\end{document}
```

I get the following:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexmf callig15
! I can't find file `callig15'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input callig15

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input callig15

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: callig15.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input callig15' failed to make callig15.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
! Font T1/calligra/m/n/12=callig15 at 17.28003pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

I tried creating my own `texmf/tex/latex/calligra` directory with callig15.mf and calligra.mf in it and running `texhash` on it according to the [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX), but this did not change anything. According to `dlocate`, calligra is located in the `texlive-latex-extra` package, which I have installed. `dlocate` does not find callig15, however. Could this be the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: `mf`-files should go in `texmf/fonts/source`.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this might be a [bug in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-extra/+bug/137640) which hasn't been addressed. I removed the package and installed with the [TeX Live installer](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html), and it's working now.