# calligra error finding callig15 redux

Tags: calligra

This question has been asked before, in particular in[this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103239/error-finding-callig15) which for some completely inexplicable reason was closed because it was unlikely to be of help to future readers.    An answer would certainly be helpful to me, and I imagine many other readers. Since the last question on this topic that I could find on the web was dated 2013, I'm hoping that some  way of resolving the problem has been identified by somebody.    To reiterate virtually verbatim that thread, here's the minimal example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calligra}
\begin{document}
\calligra
This is a test of a calligraphy font.
\end{document}
```

Here's the message i get I run it:

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm callig15
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input callig15
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf callig15
! I can't find file `callig15'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input callig15

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input callig15

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: callig15.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input callig15' failed to make callig15.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
You have some remaining errors
Font T1/calligra/m/n/12=callig15 at 17.28003pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) fil
```

Any help resolving this issue would be most appreciated.

Comment: You have an obsolete version of TeX Live (2013) and there's no point in fixing it. Fully  Install the current version as per the instructions at [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/43189) (replace 2015 with 2016) and the issue will go away.

Comment: Thanks!    Am ready to install, but am not sure what to do with my current installation.    This link "http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127898/clean-uninstall-of-tex-live-for-upgrading-to-the-next-version"  says run parallel versions but my version doesn't seem to allow that, e.g., pdftex in /usr/bin is an actual file not a link to the 2013 version.     So I'm worried about my new version tripping over the old one.      Should I completely delete the old version, and if so how?   Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Probably your current Tex Live was installed from your linux distro repositories. Better uninstall it first (not delete it). Try the steps from [How to remove everything related to TeX Live for fresh install on Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu) (adapt the year accordingly).

Comment: Yep, it was installed with the distro repository   I followed http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu to uninstall and tried to install afresh as per http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#95373 but the installation keeps crashing.  @alwaysask, would you mind looking at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321650/texlive-installation-aborted-after-hours-of-installation-restarting-without-dup for details, please?

Comment: Most likely download error. My advice is to download the entire ISO file from https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html . I download it through torrent (it's the fastest way -> 10-15 mins), mount the ISO (open the ISO with Disk Image Mounter), run `install-tl` from there and all is done in another 20-30 mins. All the rest as per "How to install "vanilla" bla bla "

Comment: P.S. TexLive will need to be updated after install from ISO.

Comment: Fabulous thanks very much, iso worked fine, nearly there.    Problem with updating, when I run `tlmgr update --all`  I get root@E5570:2016/bin/x86_64-linux#tlmgr update --all
Can't locate TeXLive/TLConfig.pm in @INC (you may need to install the TeXLive::TLConfig module) (@INC contains: /../../texmf-dist/scripts/texlive /../../tlpkg /etc/perl / .    The relevant files *are* where they should be, but the perl script apparenly isn't processing @INC.   Since I don't do perl,  I can't fix this.     When I ran install-tl using the iso, I accepted all of the defaults, maybe I shouldn't have?

Comment: You need to follow all steps from "How to install "vanilla" ...", including setting the PATH and relogin, make sure your Tex Live installation works, make a test run (the above MWE for example) and *then* update with `tlmgr`.

Comment: Yup, all worked fine once I did the extra steps, though I'm completely baffled as to what's going on.   Anyway thanks for your patience.