# differing checksums problem when installing TexLive2018

Tags: installing

I am trying to install TexLive 2018 running

```
sudo ./install-tl
```

but I get a problem

```
TLUtils::check_file: removing /tmp/edGCyjp_NY/sG1bxDft5t/biber.x86_64-linux.tar.xz, checksums differ:
TLUtils::check_file:   TL=c57a3671f8b39e6d91f2b8a8ea7ef1b94547a34c0cf31fb9607bb5b9c85964436a38d18e46d6bc8ebc24aa8d650dfa69b14b7c2bca39d869f99f487bd9a1af4d, arg=0cca577ea163993847ecac346d28f8890f6ee40904496b62074f179a066405afffea1c5c977de95cd474d9a4ce67c03e84b9c321a4512c47402944c82de303f0
TLPDB::_install_package: downloading did not succeed
Installation failed.
```

I have already rerun the installation multiple times and each time it fails on a different file.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Some replies to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321650/texlive-installation-aborted-after-hours-of-installation-restarting-without-dup may help you. In particular, selecting a mirror worked for me.